# How to put an arrow into a UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uilabel

Hi I'm trying to put an arrow into a UILabel's text but it is not working. I'm trying the following code

```
 NSString *labeltext = @"➜"; 
 label.text = labeltext;
```

But that makes the app crash!

[image]

(if you go to the edit menu and go to special characters then it is the 10th rightwards arrow)

.

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Does it work with other characters? Also, crash log, error message, stack trace?

Comment: Please show a bit more code than just that one line.  I'd like to see the actual line that assigns the "`UILabel`".

Comment: Oh sorry I put didn't include that by accident

Comment: Where do you get the arrow from? Did you copy from somehwre else? I tested this using the special characters menu in XCode and worked fine.

Comment: if you go to the edit menu and go to special characters then it is the 10th rightwards arrow

Comment: Where exactly is your label allocated?

Comment: How about breaking where the crash actually happens and showing us a stack.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Code should be working by just writing the special character directly in the code as written in the question also

```
label.text=@"➜";
```

but in case it is not working then there are alternative ways to print the special characters in IOS, You need to use Unicode character of this sign , check out this page [codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) and after getting the code just do like as follows

```
    UniChar ucode = 0x2794;
    NSString *codeString = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&ucode length:1];
    [label setText:codeString];
```

OR Just write directly like as follows

```
label.text=@"\u2794"; // this is the unicode for right arrow
```

in **Swift**:

```
lable.text="\u{2794}"
```

Comment: second couldn't get first one to work (how would you put it in "yourcharactercode")

Comment: i tried second way just now on my xcode and i know it works and i have tried it before also. if first is not working for you then just try the second one, anyways it works and will help your cause

Comment: check my updated answer, now i added working code, both ways work... if it helps your cause then let me know

Comment: did you even try?  without looking at the link you are telling you don't think it is correct?? what is your working environment? this is tested on Xcode 4.6 and IOS 6.1.

Comment: i think you have some other issue with the code, because this code is in working form which I have posted, I have used it in my applications.

Comment: @gulliver007 there is no need for any of this. The original arrow text in the original question is just fine.

Comment: @rmaddy you are right, there are different ways to do one thing, if it does not work in simple way then there are always Unicode people can use. all solutions work.

Comment: My point is that your answer doesn't address the question. There is nothing wrong with the original code so posting an answer that gives alternate code is kind of pointless. The problem is the question is missing any useful information. At the moment there is not enough to offer any real answer to the problem.

Comment: I don't agree about alternate code is pointless. even it does not address the issue but as I said there could be different ways to do deal with problems within IOS  sometimes things works differently in different IOS versions, there can be alternatives. as far as original question is concerned yes the code works that way.

Comment: ill mark up for helping but The code is correct because it works like this `NSString *LabelText = @"Hello";` but not like this `UniChar ucode = 0x2794;
    NSString *codeString = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&ucode length:1];
NSString *LabelText = codeString;`

Comment: Yes you're right it is to do with the code! THANKS!! (its sorted now)